# Java.exe access is denied

Tags: java, windows, access-denied

I have problem with access to java.exe from not parent directory.

Windows Vista Home Premium, JDK 7.

I need to execute java.exe from any directory, but when I try to run it from Command Promt, I get message "Access is denied". I configured all related environment variables. Access rights to this file allow me to run it. All folders have read permissions.

If I run it from parent directory, everything is OK.

Does anybody know what's the problem?

Comment: are you login from other account than Administrator ?

Comment: It's possible that issue wthat I had installed both jre and jdk. when I removed jre, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of any explanation apart from the obvious one; i.e. that in reality you have NOT configured the environment variables correctly for the command prompt.

- You might have set the PATH variable incorrectly.
- You might not have restarted the command shell after changing the environment variables.

(I don't think this can be a permissions issue if you can execute `java.exe` using the full pathname but not `java`.)

Comment: No, Path is set correctly, and I did restart system. When I do "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\"java.exe it works. my path variable is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\"

Answer (score 0):

Try running cmd.exe with "Run As Administrator".

Answer (score 0):

(2019) Necromancing...

Today I was happily doing some %JAVA_HOME%\BIN\KeyTool.exe, when suddenly a blue band over my screen appeared where it said that Access denied and that the program wasn't created for this platform. I had used KeyTool on this virtual machine over a 100 times?

This is how I stumbled upon this question.

Since internet didn't help my, I just uninstalled java, and re-installed it again, and Wham Bam Alakazam: it works again. So instead of searching what's wrong: just reinstall and within 4 minutes you're airborn again.